# The ring structure on the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading the section [Rational maps](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01RR) from Stacks Project, and have encountered a problem in the paragraph following tag 01RG:

> Recall that we have the canonical identification $\text{Mor}(T,\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}) = \Gamma(T,\mathcal{O}_T)$ for any scheme $T$, see Schemes, Example 15.2. Hence $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}$ is a ring-object in the category of schemes. More precisely, the morphisms
> $$\begin{align} 
> +:\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}\times \mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}} &\longrightarrow \mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}} \\ 
> (f,g)&\longmapsto f+g \\
> *:\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}\times \mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}} &\longrightarrow \mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}} \\
> (f,g)&\longmapsto fg
> \end{align}$$
> satisfy all the axioms of the addition and multiplication in a ring (commutative with 1 as always). Hence also the set of rational maps into $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}$ has a natural ring structure.

By the canonical identification it is clear that the set of rational maps into $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}$ has a natural ring structure, but I wonder what should be the definition of the addition and multiplication on $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}$ that making it a ring-object in the category of schemes. The induced addition and multiplication on $\text{Mor}(T,\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}})$  must be compatible with addition and multiplication in the ring $\Gamma(T,\mathcal{O}_T)$ under the canonical identification, for any scheme $T$. Can we write the morphisms $+,*$ explicitly ? Is there some natural definition of the morphisms ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: 1. [Pictures of text are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged): they are not accessible nor easily searchable. Please typset your posts with MathJax. 2. When referring to the Stacks Project, please refer to the [tags](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tags) - these are markers that are guaranteed to never change, whereas the numbering of results or chapters may change as the project is updated. Your text comes from [tag 01RR](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01RR), for instance.

Comment: OK, thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is the usual one, corresponding to the ring maps
$$\begin{split}
m_+\colon \mathbb{Z}[T]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[T]\otimes \mathbb{Z}[T],&\ T\mapsto 1\otimes T+T\otimes 1\\
m_*\colon \mathbb{Z}[T]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[T]\otimes \mathbb{Z}[T],&\ T\mapsto T\otimes T.
\end{split}$$

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks!